# dropdown menu option only making it to database when $_SESSION variable set

Tags: php, html, session, drop-down-menu

**tl,dr:**  if(isset($_SESSION["school"])) == true, then it works, otherwise it does not.

So on my front page, there is a dropdown menu that sets $_SESSION["school"] if the user decides they need more information about their local branch.  Then, I want to make sure they have it set correctly during registration.  So, I have a dropdown menu that displays $_SESSION["school"] if it exists, then displays all branches below just in case they need to change.  When $_SESSION["school"] does not exist, I want it to only display the list of schools, and disregard $_SESSION["school"].

What happens with this code, though, is if any $_SESSION["school"] is set, the information makes it to the database, even if you change the dropdown choice during registration.  If no $_SESSION["school"] is set, the information never makes it to the database even when setting it during registration.  More interestingly, I have validation on this blank, which means that the page is recognizing that the menu != ""...the information just doesn't get all the way to the database if $_SESSION["school"] has not been previously set.  I think the code below is the relevant code because this is where I use $_SESSION["school"] to set a menu option, but I can post some of the other pieces if you need it.

schoolsList.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['school']) && $_SESSION['school']==true) {
    echo
    '<option value="'.$_SESSION["school"].'">'.$_SESSION["school"].'</option>';
}

echo
'<option value=""></option>
<option value="Indiana University">Indiana University</option>
<option value="Purdue University">Purdue University</option>';

?>
```

in my form:

```
<select 
                            class="school"
                            id="school"
                            name="school"
                            >';

                    include "schoolsList.php";

                echo
                '</select>';
```

Comment: The fact that it takes 2 paragraphs to explain what you want, and still leave me confused, makes me think that you really aren't sure what you want it to do. Please try to make this concise and more clear.

Comment: well, the first paragraph is what i want it to do, the second is what it is doing...how can I explain further, in short my menu is only sending info to the database when isset($_SESSION["school")==true

Comment: the problem with many questions is they include too much business logic. Questions that narrow down the problem tend to get better answers than those who don't.

Comment: where is the rest of your code? i.e. all validation stages and queries to that database.

Comment: I don't now what your "menu" is. Is that your drop down list? You haven't provided the rest of the drop down list code

Comment: Your if-statement does not make sense. Why aren't you using isset() if you want to test if it's set?

Comment: yes, sorry I am adding it now to the top.

Comment: updated again based on answer below using isset(), still only working when $_SESSION["school"] previously set

Comment: From what I see here, it looks Ok. The problem is likely originating in another part of the code that isn't shown.

Comment: Hehe, love the way the OP (original poster) edited the question putting my answer code on his question. radleybobins, SO style you should accept answers that solve your problem and try to dissect your problem into all available chunks asking questions for each needed piece. It's a divide and conquer technique.

Answer (score 1):

```
// will always validate to true except when $_SESSION["school"] is not set  
if($_SESSION["school"])
```

This should leave you more than room to improve your code.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['school']) && $_SESSION['school']==true)
{
    // do something here
}
```

PHP is very allowing on how you set variables and switch between types so these evaluations can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for writing the improvement.  I can see how this would be a better way to write the if statement.  I'm just confused because I'm only adding an option, otherwise I'm not changing the form.  But, adding the option is forcing the entire form to work.